# website javascript creating GWT 404 error

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, http-status-code-404, google-crawlers

Absolute novice in need of help and advice. I'm getting the following URL errors in GWT search console

products/enquiry_form/           response code: 404

Ive tracked the error to the following javascript on every page of my website

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#enquiry_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
        var product_id = button.data('product') // Extract info from data-* attributes
        var company = button.data('company') // Extract info from data-* attributes
        var modal = $(this)

            $.get( "/products/enquiry_form/"+product_id, function( data ) {
                modal.find('.modal-title').text('New enquiry to ' + company)
                modal.find('.modal-data').html( data );
            });
        })  

        $('.enquiry_form_submit').on('click', function(){
            $('.enquiry_form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be great,

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 means page not found.

```
$.get( "/products/enquiry_form/"+product_id, function( data ) {
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('New enquiry to ' + company)
            modal.find('.modal-data').html( data );
        });
```

The above line generates the error.
I can't give you a definitive answer because I don't know where the correct page is, but as a conjecture, you're treating products as if it is in the base html directory on the server, instead try `"./products/enquiry_form/"+product_id`
.
If this doesn't work, it is possible that the product id doesn't exist. Try removing it from the ajax request as a test.

Without knowing the directory structure I can't complete this answer.

Comment: Thank you Mathew for your answer. Just to be clear the script works as it is,the forms work well on every page of the website. The problem is that google see the "/products/enquiry_form/" as a 404 error, page not found when it crawls the pages

Comment: Right I agree. This is a subpage of your site correct? Then the page would only load if the URL was `http://yoursite.com/products/enquiry_form` 

But since you're using google crawlers, if your site has a robots.txt it could be causing the error.